# Ubuntu 10.04 on vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124

Tags: vmware-player

I'm using vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124 on Windows 7 Pro as host and installed Ubuntu 10.04 as guest OS. On booting into Ubuntu , it cannot detect the keyboard. How do I fix this. I also installed a Opensue 11.1 VM and the keybaord worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work-around is to enable the virtual keyboard (through the accessibility options at the login page). Login and then make a quick change to  `/etc/default/console-setup`. Find XBVARIANT and remove the value for it, leaving you with
`XKBVARIANT=""`

Some other options are mentioned in the comments of this blog post: http://www.solo-technology.com/blog/2010/05/01/ubuntu-10-0-4-vmware-and-no-keyboard

Comment: just to add that after selecting the Universal access and OSK, you need to reboot the OS once to get the OSK...